# Datatables and JEditable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, jeditable

Just starting with php, datatables and jeditable, I can get my table to load and looks ok, when I click on a record in the table it lets me edit the record and I am getting data when I look at the dataOut.php file in chrome developer tools, but it is not passing the record identifier.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('#users').dataTable( {
    } );
 
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#users').dataTable();
      
    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    oTable.$('td').editable( 'dataOut.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
            window.location.reload();
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id_user'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            }
        },
        "height": "14px",
        "width": "100%"
    } );
} );
 
 
</script>
```

```html
<table id="users" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>id</th>
                   <th>First Name</th>
                   <th>Last Name</th>
                   <th>Username</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Role Code</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
         <tbody>
         <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
     foreach ($conn->query($sql)as $row){
      echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['id_user'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['realname'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['role'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
     }
    ?>
     </tbody>
           <tfoot>
               <tr>
       <td>id</td>
                <td>iFirstname</td>
                <td>Lastname</td>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Role Code</td>
               </tr>
           </tfoot>
           
     </table>
```

And when I change a surname from Lewis to Lane, here is the result in chrome developer

array(4) { ["value"]=> string(4) "Lane" ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["row_id"]=> string(0) "" ["column"]=> string(1) "2" }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but I noticed an error, and I suspect this could be your problem.

In your `foreach` loop you're looping through `$conn->query()` which is a mysqli_result object. You need to call the `fetch_assoc` method. Additionally, this needs to be done through a `while` loop instead of a `foreach` loop. This is because `fetch_assoc` is function that gets the next row that matches your query, rather than returning one big array with all of the matching rows. When there are no more rows, it returns null and therefore ends the `while` loop. Try this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('#users').dataTable( {
    } );
 
    /* Init DataTables */
    var oTable = $('#users').dataTable();
      
    /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
    oTable.$('td').editable( 'dataOut.php', {
        "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
            window.location.reload();
        },
        "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
            return {
                "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id_user'),
                "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2]
            }
        },
        "height": "14px",
        "width": "100%"
    } );
} );
 
 
</script>
```

```html
<table id="users" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>id</th>
                   <th>First Name</th>
                   <th>Last Name</th>
                   <th>Username</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Role Code</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
         <tbody>
         <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
     while($row = ($conn->query($sql))->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['id_user'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['realname'] . '</td>';
       echo '<td>' . $row['role'] . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
     }
    ?>
     </tbody>
           <tfoot>
               <tr>
       <td>id</td>
                <td>iFirstname</td>
                <td>Lastname</td>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Role Code</td>
               </tr>
           </tfoot>
           
     </table>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Thanks, that's giving me more data, I guess my issue is that the data returned does not include the primary key relating to the database record.  Data returned:       array(4) { ["value"]=> string(10) "Peter.Lane" ["id"]=> string(0) "" ["row_id"]=> string(0) "" ["column"]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: Got it, my error:    Changed this line:   "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id_user'), to   "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),  and put an identifier in the <tr> tag in the table targeting id.  Thanks